# Why Bitcoind cannot run simultaneosly?

Tags: bitcoind

Someday, my bitcoind was running and I opend another terminal and typed bitcoind on the terminal but, bitcoind which is running was shutdown. so I should have run the first node and have another node connected to the node.
Definitely, I think there is some critical reason that developers set the policy in this case, but I don't know why.

Do you know?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I gave a link to a possible other question that may help you do what you're trying to do, but the very short answer to the question as you asked it here is simply that `bitcoind` needs on on-disk database, and if you want to two instances, you'll need to configure them to maintain their databases in separate places.

Comment: @PieterWuille Thanks :) it helped for understanding.